# Spark streaming and database caching

Tags: database, caching, apache-spark, streaming, rdd

I have a Spark streaming application which does lot of database access. We are using an abstraction layer (basically a JAVA library) which maintains CACHE to access database. This CACHE layer (at client side) helps to speed up query processing.

I know that in context of Normal host (non spark) this really helps. But when it comes to Spark Streaming I doubt whether this CLIENT side caching would help as data may not remain cached for a long time as Spark Streaming behaves differently.

Can somebody please clarify.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly please clarify !

Comment: I want to know in Spark Streaming if my job is accessing database through a CLIENT side caching layer, will it really help in speeding up the query? My understanding is that whatever caching is done by caching layer will be valid only for that job which I guess in Spark Streaming runs for a very short time. Also per my understanding this cache can not be used/shared by other jobs running on the Executor.

Comment: That depends upon the architecture of the cache i guess ! And I suppose your understanding is correct here ! If you wanna speed up then you may want to use the Off heap caching !

Comment: So are you saying if my caching layer uses off-heap memory then all my spark streaming jobs (on same executor) will be able to access this cache?

Comment: See my point is Executor does not know anything it just knw okay this is the place where I have to look for data and then I have to perform these operations as per the DAG which it recieved and the store the data accordingly so it does not matter much from where it takes up the data(as long as an API is available for that) , If you want to cache the large amount of data for the jobs (maybe used for window operations) then you can go for the off heap caching or the MEM caching as per your cluster resources

Comment: Are you saying enable Spark Streaming to use off-heap memory? My case is little different. Here my application does not do any caching. But the underlying caching layer (a library that my application uses) does it internally/transparently. I am not sure if it uses off-heap or not AND also whether it uses any Spark API for persisting (which looks less likely).

Comment: Hence I guess no it treats it same caching on client side will give you a very little enhancement in this case I guess ! Yet I also want to know other persons opinion